# Use properties of the parent component in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a form with three fields

```
<div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
            Form
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
              <label>ID </label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" [value]="question.id" name="id"
                [(ngModel)]=question.id>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
              <label>LABEL </label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" [value]="question.label" name="label"
                [(ngModel)]=question.label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
              <label>TYPE </label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" [value]="question.type" name="type"
                [(ngModel)]=question.type>
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in the component I have that question to which I refer

```
question: any = {
    id: null,
    label,
    type: null
  };
```

Now I would like to pass the two of those inputs to a new component, so that something like this is left

```
<div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
            Form
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <form>
<two-inputs></two-inputs>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
              <label>TYPE </label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" [value]="question.type" name="type"
                [(ngModel)]=question.type>
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but if I create the two-inputs component with this html

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
              <label>ID </label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" [value]="question.id" name="id"
                [(ngModel)]=question.id>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
              <label>LABEL </label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" [value]="question.label" name="label"
                [(ngModel)]=question.label>
            </div>
```

It does not recognize the question because of course, it does not exist in the component but exists in the parent component ... does it have an easy way to reference it without having to resort to services, @Input or @Output?

Comment: [Read this](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/)

Comment: The simplest is to provide the questions-object through an Input. That will only give you one additional line of code